# Get value from a HashMap using a byte[] key

Tags: java

I'm trying to add some values to a map as

```
Map<byte[], byte[]> samplerMap = new HashMap<>();
samplerMap.put(Bytes.toBytes("key"), Bytes.toBytes("value"));
```

To fetch the value from map,

```
samplerMap.get(Bytes.toBytes("key"))
```

When I'm debugging this, I'm getting a `null` value. Are there any special case when using a `byte[]` as a key of a map. How may I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `fromBytes` somewhere?  Also, can include the full definition of your map?

Comment: That Bytes class, apache?

Comment: Yes @Jorge.V. apache Bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that two `byte[]` use the `Object.hashCode`, which tests for the *instance* of the object. Two array instances as created by `new byte[...]` will yield two different hash codes, keys, and hence almost always null is returned.

Furthermore `equals` does not work too, hence `byte[]` as key is no option.

You could use the string itself, as you are actual doing `"key".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Or create wrapper class:

```
public class ByteArray {
    public final byte[] bytes;
    public ByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object rhs) {
        return rhs != null && rhs instanceof ByteArray
            && Arrays.equals(bytes, ((ByteArray)rhs).bytes);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an array as a key of a `HashMap` since arrays don't override the default implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`. Therefore two different array instances that contain the exact same elements will be considered as different keys.

You can use a `List<Byte>` as key instead.

Comment: While you _can_ use `List<Byte>`, the overhead is rather awful (probably over 800% on a 64-bits JVM), though I don't know whether this matters for OP's use case. Doesn't Java have something like [`com.google.protobuf.ByteString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString) built in yet?